# Beautiful Soup throws `IndexError`

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website using **Python 2.7** and **Beautiful Soup 3.2**. I am new to both languages, but from the documentation I got a bit started.

I am reading the next documentations:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents
http://thepcspy.com/read/scraping-websites-with-python/

What I do and have now (part that fails):

```
# Import the classes that are needed
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# URL to scrape and open it with the urllib2
url = 'http://www.wiziwig.tv/competition.php?competitionid=92&part=sports&discipline=football'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# Turn the saced source into a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

# From the source HTML page, search and store all <td class="home">..</td> and it's content
hometeamsTd = soup.findAll('td', { "class" : "home" })
# Loop through the tag and store only the needed information, being the home team
hometeams = [tag.contents[1] for tag in hometeamsTd]

# From the source HTML page, search and store all <td class="home">..</td> and it's content
awayteamsTd = soup.findAll('td', { "class" : "away" })
# Loop through the tag and store only the needed information, being the away team
awayteams = [tag.contents[1] for tag in awayteamsTd]
```

Content of `tag.contents` for the **hometeamsTd** looks like this:

```
[
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Harkemase Boys', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-6077" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'RKC Waalwijk', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-427" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Dutch KNVB Beker', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-6758" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'PSV', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-3" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Ajax', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-2" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Dutch KNVB Beker', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-6758" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'SC Heerenveen', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-14" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Feyenoord', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-9" />],
    [<img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />, u'Dutch KNVB Beker', <img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" alt="fav icon" class="fav off" id="team-6758" />]
]
```

Content of `tag.contents` for the **awayteamsTd** looks like this:

```
[
    [u'Away-team'], 
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-13" />, u'NEC', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />], 
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-11" />, u'Heracles', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />], 
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-428" />, u'Stormvogels Telstar', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />], 
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-419" />, u'FC Volendam', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />],
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-7" />, u'FC Twente', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />],
    [<img src="/gfx/favourite_off.gif" class="fav off" alt="fav icon" id="team-415" />, u'FC Dordrecht', <img class="flag" src="/gfx/flags/nl.gif" alt="nl" />]
]
```

Problems I try to solve, but don't quite get yet is:

- The code `awayteams = [tag.contents[1] for tag in awayteamsTd]` throughs an error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Which is ofcourse correct, because as you can see in the output of `tag.contents` for **awayteamsTd**, there is an first entry `[u'Away-team']`. This is why it is failing. But how can I remove/skip this one?
- Within the hometeams output everything is working, but I would like to exclude the ones where the text **Dutch KNVB Beker** occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "away" cell (column name) is inside a td with "away" class:

```
<thead class="title">
    ...
    <tr class="sub">
      ...  
      <td>Home-team</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="away">Away-team</td>
      <td class="broadcast">Broadcast</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</thead>
```

Just skip it by using slicing:

```
awayteamsTd = soup.findAll('td', { "class" : "away" })[1:]
```

Also, if you want to exclude `Dutch KNVB Beker` from the list of home teams, add a condition to the list comprehension expression:

```
hometeams = [tag.contents[1] for tag in hometeamsTd if tag.contents[1] != 'Dutch KNVB Beker']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awayteams = []
for tag in awayteamsTd:
    if len(tag.contents) > 1:
        awayteams.append(tag.contents[1])
```